# Workday Function with IF Else in VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

i m trying to write macro to replicate the following Excel formula .

```
= if($L2>(workday($I2,7)),">T+7",if($L2>(workday($I2,2)),">T+2","SPOT"))
```

where L2 denotes some Older dates in DD/MM/YYYY format & I is current date.
Please suggest.

The data look like this
[image: The data look like this]

Comment: From which cell did you copy this example?

Comment: Screenshot: Level expert ;) • Would writing the formula with VBA be an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code finds the last used row in column "I" first.
Then it loops over all rows and fills an array which is in the end assigned to the resulting column:

```
Private Sub WorkDayDifferenceSub()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim myResults() As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("YourWorksheetnameHere")

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim myResults(2 To lastRow, 1 To 1)

    For r = 2 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(r, 12) > WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(ws.Cells(r, 9), 7) Then
            myResults(r, 1) = ">T+7"
        Else
            If ws.Cells(r, 12) > WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(ws.Cells(r, 9), 2) Then
                myResults(r, 1) = ">T+2"
            Else
                myResults(r, 1) = "SPOT"
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    ws.Range("AG2:AG" & lastRow).Value = myResults

    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Asger. But I m getting compile error. I want the output comments in  range("AG2:AG84500"). I have total rows around 84500..In above code where the destination output will be reflecting?

Comment: Hi Asger, getting runtime error 9 at "redim my results(2 to last row,1 to 1)" section..pls suggest

Comment: Column I having value till row num 84472.

Comment: Thanks Asger. It worked. Is there any way to remove as I will be running multiple macros under one command.

Comment: Please explain further. Do you want to clear column AG? `ws.Range("AG2:AG100000).ClearContents`

Comment: Not like that. I mean to say this macro will be the last one. Before that few more codes will be running to slice n dice my output sheet. So I just want to skip n message box with last row number and want to have a a completed message box. Is it clear?

Comment: Of course, just delete the line `msgbox LastRow` forever. It was meant for debugging only, and add a `MsgBox "Ready :)"` wherever you want in your code. If it works now please consider to "accept the answer" as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: How should I put a range for the 'lastrow' because my lastrow will vary between 75000 t0 100000..Pls suggest..

Comment: The formula to get the variable "lastRow" has already been there in my answer (I only changed it to a faster one just a minute ago). Please try it and if it works, please consider to "accept the answer" as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.